# Datatables responsive, set specific options

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTables with the responsive extension on our web application, but I have a question.

When the table is made responsive, it should hide the pagination option.

I tried this with "bLengthChange": false:

```js
 $(function () {
        $("#table1").DataTable({
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Dutch.json"
            },
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            responsive: {
                details: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                "bLengthChange": false
            },
            columnDefs: [ {
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false,
                targets:   0
            } ],
        });
    });
```

However, this does not work. My target is that I can see the pagination amount dropdown menu on fullscreen, but that option should be hidden if responsive.

Can I add options like bLengthChange specific to the "responsive" state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add options like bLengthChange specific to the "responsive"
>   state?

No, you cannot. Try inspect `$.fn.dataTable.Responsive.defaults` again, as I believe you already have done.  It does not give so much sense either, the responsive extension *is* an extension while `lengthMenu` is a core feature. If you want to hide the lengthMenu you would need to reinitialise the table or do something hackish that may or may not conflict with other features or other extensions.  But you can do the hack yourself. Hook into the [**`responsive-resize`**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/responsive-resize) event and hide or show the `lengthMenu` according to the responsive status :

```js
table.on( 'responsive-resize', function ( e, datatable, columns ) {
  var $lengthMenu = $('.dataTables_length')
  var count = columns.reduce( function (a,b) {
    return b === false ? a+1 : a;
  }, 0 );
  if (count>0 && $lengthMenu.is(':visible')) $lengthMenu.hide()
  if (count<= 0 && !$lengthMenu.is(':visible')) $lengthMenu.show()
} );
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v1dnxLkg/**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

Fixed it with this CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    div.dataTables_wrapper > div.row > div > div.dataTables_length{
        display: none;
    }
}
```